# Redirect \t \t output in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

While doing some random thing I checked the commands using <kbd>⇥</kbd>-completion (<kbd>⇥</kbd><kbd>⇥</kbd> on an empty prompt), it then proceeded to show me the longest paged list ever made, or so it seemed.

That's when it occurred to me to attempt redirecting it, just for fun; but after many attempts I still can't.

One of the commands I was sure was going to work was `printf \t\t > filename` but didn't, obviously; neither the longer form version `printf '%s' "\t\t" > filename`. I have a list of VT100 escape codes somewhere in my notes — *the ones that start with `\033`- or `\003`-something* — but I kind of forgot how I named the file so it might as well be lost.

Is it doable?

Comment: Maybe use "script" to log all the terminal output?